# How do I get the component to redirect with a handleClick?

Tags: reactjs

I am working on a ProductList component, that when you click on the div with the button in it, it should take you to the ProductDetail component and the url associated with it, but so far nothing has worked.

This is about my 10th different way of doing it and I honestly don't know what else to try at this point. My error message I am currently getting is 'upc is undefined' and before that it just returned 'undefined' as a part of the url. Any help would be much appreciated, thank you.

```
const ProductList = ({ result, upc }) => {
  const history = useHistory()
  const [itemId, setItemId] = useState('')
  const containerStyles = {
    height: '100vh',
    overflow: 'auto',
    textAlign: 'center',
    padding: '5vh',
    alignItems: 'center'
  }
  console.log(result)
  const handleClick = (id) => e => {
    e.preventDefault()
    console.log(id)
    history.push(`/productdetail/${result[id].upc}`)
  }

  return (
    <Grid container direction='column'>
      <div style={containerStyles}>
        <div>
          <button>
            {!result
              ? (
                <h1>No results found</h1>
              )
              : (
                <div>
                  {result.map((item) => (
                    <p key={item.id} onClick={handleClick(item.id)}>
                      {item.name}
                      <img src={item.image_url} />
                      {item.upc}
                    </p>
                  ))}
                </div>
              )}
          </button>
        </div>

      </div>
    </Grid>
  )
}

export default ProductList
```

Comment: What is the value of `result` or `result[id]` when `handleClick` is invoked? Why not pass the `item.upc` value to the callback instead?

Comment: Result is the name of the array of data that I am getting. I tried the id part because I had no idea what else to try. I might not fully understand your question though, I am sorry.

Comment: Do you mean calling it in the url? Because I've tried that.

Comment: I meant try logging `result[id]` *in* the callback. `result[id]` assumes the `id` is the property accessor of `result`, i.e. if `id = 'test'`, then `resut[id]` is the same as `result.test`. `result` is an array though so this is likely *not* the case. The other comment, pass the upc instead, i.e. `onClick={handleClick(item.upc)` and do `history.push(\`/productdetail/${upc}\`)`.

Comment: Sadly the second one does not work, but it also did not come back with an error message. I also logged the result[id] and it did come back as undefined in the console.

Comment: The issue is that `result` is an array, so unless `item.id` is a value that matches the array index `item` occupies it is highly likely that `result[id]` will just always be undefined. Please check what `result` is when the `handleClick` callback is invoked, or just update your question to include what the `result` prop value is when it's passed to `ProductList`.

Answer (score 0):

Please add on your app.js router the following prop

```
<Router history={history}>
....
</Router>
```

Comment: Yes it's there!

Comment: can you mark it as a correct answer please. This motivates me to keep answering more questions.